# Help identifying component (LED matrix PCB)

Tags: led, identification, surface-mount, led-driver

I have a led matrix PCB without a driver and I'm trying to figure out how to control it. I'm having trouble identifying one of the components on the PCB.

Here is a scheme of a part of the PCB:
[image: PCB part]

These 6-pin parts have WDFN-6 package or similar. They have labels `AP1` (I also met `APN` for the same parts). Here are the pictures:
[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

I thought it might be a [Dual LDO Regulator](http://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/r/t/rt9011_richtek.pdf) or something similar, but it doesn't match the actual scheme.

Please provide any thoughts on what it might be.

Comment: Are you sure pins 3 and 4 are not connected on all those chips?  How many layers on the board?

Comment: They are connected the same way as the first (left) one, I just skip this to not overcomplicate the scheme. Each unknown SMD component has a PUMH1 connected (double resistor-equipped transistor). I don't know how many layers the bord has, at least 2.
Also, note that the last (right) SMD is rotated 180 deg. @HandyHowie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly [dual PNP transistors](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nss60100dmt-d.pdf) part number NSS60100DMT.

They are symmetrical so a 180° rotation does not matter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried to replace my "unknown" chips on the scheme with the dual pnp transistors you shared. I know that this circuit should allow enabling a single random led. I cannot figure out if there is a way to achieve this using dual transistors. Do you think it is possible at all?

Comment: I didn't really try to guess your circuit. If you probe (unpowered, of course) with a diode test setting it might allow you to rule out or suggest other options.